# jquery 2 different slide toggle doesnt work properly

Tags: java, jquery, slidetoggle

Hey I'm completley new to jquery and java.
As shown in the picture I have two texts that slides down which have to work separate, but the right one doesnt work properly.

http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3485/3xjuqtbh_jpg.htm

Here my jquery code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"</script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").slideToggle();
    });
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("enter").click(function(){
    $("pi").slideToggle();
    });
    });
    </script>
```

and my HTML code:

```
 <div id="Max Mustermann">

 [...]

 <p style="display:none;">Hallelulja</p><button>Read more...</button>

 </div>



 <div id="Max Mustermann 2">

 [...]

 <pi style="display:none;">Hallelulja</pi><enter>Read more...</enter>

 </div>
```

How does the code have to look that the right one work properly? 
Thanks for every Help!

Comment: You need only one $(document).ready function. Put the both rule in. I supose that one is ignored.Also, the "pi" sound weird. Make a div/paragraph/span with class/id pi. Have you check, it is matched like this?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try giving your `p` and `button` some `id or class` , so that it would know which element to toggle

2) change your `pi` and `enter` to p or button tag

3)Only one `$(document).ready` fucntion is required. Put all your scripts into that.

4)You can also try giving `display:none` using CSS class.

5)If there are gonna be many number of `slideToggle()` functionality, rather than writing it for each button , you need to write the code generically.

Please see the edited code below

HTML:

```
<div id="Max Mustermann">    
 [...]    
 <p id="para-1" class="displaynone">Hallelulja</p>
 <button id="button-1">Read more...</button>    
 </div> 

 <div id="Max Mustermann 2">    
 [...]    
 <p id="para-2" class="displaynone">Hallelulja</pi>
 <button id="button-2">Read more...</button>    
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .displaynone{display:none;}
```

Script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button-1").click(function(){
    $("#para-1").slideToggle();
    });       
    $("#button-2").click(function(){
    $("#para-2").slideToggle();
    });
    });
    </script>
```